# Rotate an element around another element - css

Tags: html, css, spinning

I am working with CSS, and want to do an effect where an object is moving around another object in an ellipse. I am not using a canvas, and this is my html:

```
<div>/*Content intended for ellipse movement*/</div>
<div>/*Element to ellipse around*/</div>
```

I do not have any css at this time
How do I do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps try to make the second `div` as a child with absolute position to the pivot (first `div`). And rotate the first `div`?

Comment: Please add your CSS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #9f9;
}

.high {
  background-color: #99f;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="low"></div>
<div class="high"></div>
```